# reverse on list comprehension returns nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does a call to reverse return nothing when put on the end of a list comprehension?

This does not work - lines is None

```
lines = ['{},'.format(line.replace('"', '').strip().lower()) for line in lines].reverse()
```

But this works fine - lines is my list in reverse order

```
lines = ['{},'.format(line.replace('"', '').strip().lower()) for line in lines]
lines.reverse()
```

Comment: `.reverse` **always** returns `None`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I got it now